# ionic build android error gradle error

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

ionic build android error gradle error

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in
>   opening zip file
>
> at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
>
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
>
> at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
>
> at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
>
> Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)
>
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)
>
> at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:163)
>
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
>
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
>
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
>
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
>
> at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
>
> ... 3 more
>
> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-console':Error:
>   /node/Palaroo/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code
>   1
>
> at ChildProcess.whenDone
>   (/node/Palaroo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
>
> at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>
> Error: /node/Palaroo/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with
>   exit code 1

**Can any one provide solution for this**

Comment: are you using windows or mac...

Comment: Improve formatting

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the folder /**home/USER-NAME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/**

Its happening because your gradle zip file has not downloaded correctly delete it and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

If faced error while building ionic build android

then got to this path on mac and delete everything

```
/var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/
```

If faced error while building ionic build android

then

got to this path on mac and delete everything

```
/var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/

/var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/nzipping

/var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

to

```
/var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh
```

This solves the problem